# How to count json items for each param?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have a JSON store :

```
{
    "Week": 1145,
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": 1145,       
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": 1145,        
    "From": "IN2"
},
{
    "Week": 1146,
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": 1146,
    "From": "IN2"
}
```

I want to count for each "Week", the number of "From", for example for Week 1146, i'd get IN1 = 1 and IN2 = 1 and for week 1145 i'd get IN1 = 2 and IN2 = 1.

I've written a function that loops through my data store to count IN1 and IN2 for each param:

```
countBy: function(param){
    var count = {};
    this.each(function(item){
        var type = item.get(param);
        if (Ext.isDefined(count[type])){
            count[type]++;
        } else {
            count[type] = 1;
        }                               
    });
    return count;
}
```

But the problem is that when I give it "Week" in param, it doesn't count IN1 and IN2 for each WEEK, it returns "1145" : 3 and 1146 : 2, but what i want is : "1145" : {IN1 : 2} and "1146" : {IN1 : 1}.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `From` as parameter too.

Try below:

```
countBy: function(param, param2){
    var count = {};
    this.each(function(item){
        var type = item.get(param);
        var from = item.get(param2);
        if (type in count){
            if (from in count[type]) {
              count[type][from]++;
            } else {
              count[type][from] = 1;
            } 
        } else {
            count[type] = {};
            count[type][from] = 1;
        }                               
    });
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (there is just a closing parenthese to remove after (if type in count)).
Do you know how I can get each value apart? Because I need to store the total of IN1 and IN2 for each week and use them to draw a chart.
I did this : 
    var countObject = myStore.countBy("Week","From");
    console.log(Ext.encode(countObject.IN2))
to get IN2 (I know it's very naive but I'm really new to extjs and javascript). But it returns null. I want to store them in variables and use them in my chart. Thanks in advance